# Communication with Windows Guest OS run in Qemu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu, virtio

Using a headless Ubuntu 14.04 server, I'm running a Windows 7 guest in Qemu to which I am passing through the GPU (for performance). I am writing an application for which part will be running in Linux, and part will be running in the Windows guest, and I need communication between the two. Researching this has led me to believe my best option would be using Virtio-serial drivers so I can simply communicate between the two as if they had a serial connection; this sounds fabulous, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it working.  I've found a few resources which detail the necessary Qemu command line options, such as [here](https://log.amitshah.net/2010/09/communication-between-guests-and-hosts/), but I've failed to find any resources on how to initiate communication from the *Guest's* side.  It seems most people doing this type of thing are doing so with Linux guest OSes, which I'm sure greatly simplifies things.

Network communication may not be an option, as we will most likely be passing the NIC through to the Guest OS as well (again, performance is critical for the guest OS). Even if not, that seems like an unnecessarily heavy option for simple communication between applications.

I have also considered creating an SMB share, and storing a database there that can be connected to from multiple hosts, then running mysql on the host and guest. But this also seems far less than ideal... Does anyone have any experience with this, or maybe an obvious suggestion I'm missing?

Edit:

I meant to include my qemu shell script:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -M q35 -m 3072 -cpu host -smp 4 
-bios /usr/share/qemu/bios.bin -vga none -nographic -serial mon:stdio 
-device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 
-device vfio-pci,host=00:01.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on 
-device vfio-pci,host=00:01.1,bus=root.1,addr=00.1 
-device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi 
-drive file=/utils/WES7.img,id=disk,format=raw,if=none -device ide-hd,drive=disk 
-drive file=/home/mvsuser/virtio-win-0.1-100.iso,id=virtiocd,if=none -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,drive=virtiocd 
-usb -usbdevice host:046d:C52B 
-net bridge -net nic,model=virtio 
-chardev socket,path=/tmp/port0,server,nowait,id=port0-char 
-device virtio-serial 
-device virtserialport,id=port1,name=vioserial,chardev=port0-char
```

Answer (score 1):

[The page you refer to](https://log.amitshah.net/2010/09/communication-between-guests-and-hosts/) includes [a link](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Virtio-serial_API) to the API to use from Windows guests (as well as Linux guests). I believe this is what you're looking for.

Also, the QEMU Guest Agent source code has [a working example](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=qga/channel-win32.c;h=21f9deedf6dd7a2b13e5f7c21ec99c6c7b4b0e43;hb=HEAD) of how the qemu guest agent uses virtio-serial within Windows.